# Vue.js: Invalid options in vue.config.js: "plugins" is not allowed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, sass, stylelint

I have a webpack project and I want to use Stylelint for SCSS linting. I have followed the instructions on the Stylelint website and installed:

```
"stylelint": "^12.0.1",
"stylelint-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.2",
```

And then I have put this in vue.config.js:

```
plugins: [
  new StylelintPlugin({
    files: '**/*.s?(a|c)ss'
  })
],
```

And when I start the server I get this:

```
Invalid options in vue.config.js: "plugins" is not allowed
```

I have searched high and low but I have not found anything.
Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the vue.config.js:

```
const StylelintPlugin = require('stylelint-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {

  plugins: [
    new StylelintPlugin({
      files: '**/*.s?(a|c)ss'
    })
  ],

  assetsDir: 'asset',

  configureWebpack: config => {
    config.entry = '@/wrapper/main.js'
  },

  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch')
  },

  lintOnSave: undefined,
  runtimeCompiler: true
}
```

Comment: Please, show your vue.config.js - it seems you had added plugins in wrong place

Comment: @ValeriiVoronkov I have added vue.config.js

Comment: Move your plugins into the configureWebpack object and it will be worked

Comment: @ValeriiVoronkov I have moved it to the configureWebpack object and started the development server but it hangs. It does nothing. What could be the problem?

Comment: try to comment plugin and string with require - if it will have been worked, you should clarify how exactly this plugin set's up

Answer (score 25):

The easiest way to tweak the webpack config is providing an object to the **configureWebpack** option in vue.config.js:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [new MyAwesomeWebpackPlugin()]
  }
}
```

The object will be merged into the final webpack config using webpack-merge.

Checkout https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Have you try with this syntax :

```
const StylelintPlugin = require('stylelint-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {

  assetsDir: 'asset',

  configureWebpack: config => {
    config.entry = '@/wrapper/main.js'
  },

  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch')

    config.plugin('stylelint').use(StylelintPlugin, [
      {
        files: '**/*.s?(a|c)ss'
      }
    ])
  },

  lintOnSave: undefined,
  runtimeCompiler: true
}
```

That is how we managed to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help someone

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
 configureWebpack: {
  plugins: [
   new MyAwesomeWebpackPlugin()
  ]
 }
}

// In my case i was doing below and was facing the same error
const path = require('path')
const PrerenderSPAPlugin = require('prerender-spa-plugin')

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        plugins: [
               new PrerenderSPAPlugin({
                // Required - The path to the webpack-outputted app to prerender.
                staticDir: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
                // Required - Routes to render.
                routes: ['/', '/page-path', '/another-page'],
            })
        ]
    },
    lintOnSave: false
}
```

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration